# Openfire Configuration host name issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, configuration, openfire

I'm re-configuring openfire on aws server because of a change in domain name of our site. So I uninstalled openfire and reinstalled again through rpm commands.

During admin configuration I input new domain name. However, after admin settings finished, I see in admin console server name: newdomain.com, hostname (under Environment) remains: olddomain.com

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change 2 values:

**Server Name** (Server Informations -> on bottom of ports list "Edit Properties" -> THEN first one it's Server Name)

and **xmpp.domain** in System Properties with the same value.